# Page not found when activate locale in next.js when redirect to other page

Tags: next.js, localization, internationalization, contentful

i just using localization with middleware from next.js doc. its work fine when run to / page. but when i move or redirect to other page it said "404 Page Not Found"

Here is my next.config.js

```
i18n: {
locales: ['default','en', 'it'],
defaultLocale: 'default',
localeDetection: false
},
trailingSlash: true
```

And this is my middleware.ts code:

```
const PUBLIC_FILE = /\.(.*)$/

export async function middleware(req: NextRequest) {
if (
req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/_next') ||
req.nextUrl.pathname.includes('/api/') ||
PUBLIC_FILE.test(req.nextUrl.pathname)
) {
return
}

if (req.nextUrl.locale === 'default') {
const locale = req.cookies.get('NEXT_LOCALE')?.valueOf || "en"

return NextResponse.redirect(
  new URL(`/${locale}${req.nextUrl.pathname}${req.nextUrl.search}`, req.url)
  )
 }
}
```